# The meaning of "as much as" in this sentence

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, phrase-usage

> **As much as** the weaponry it produced as one of the “arsenals of the United Nations,” the TVA itself was potent propaganda, an authoritative, living symbol of how a liberal world could be constructed postwar. ([source](https://books.google.com/books?id=7NFB2z4VDuwC&pg=PA81&lpg=PA81&dq=%22as%20much%20as%20the%20weaponry%20it%20produced%20as%20one%20of%20the%20arsenals%20of%20the%20united%20nations%22&source=bl&ots=NKiuOCCYkg&sig=p11kcqLmIpyvcGkkz3ZPI54MJXI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi99omH06LfAhXNm-AKHXSWDPUQ6AEwAHoECAAQAQ))

This usage where "as much as" is followed by a noun phrase is unfamiliar to me. I am much more familiar with constructions of "as much as" followed by a clause, such as

> even though : despite the fact that
>   *As much as I respect him, I still have to disagree with him on this point.* (source: Merriam Webster)

I can't find other sentences with similar structures to the sentence at issue at the top of this question. What does "as much as + noun phrase" mean? Despite that NP...? What does that sentence mean?

Answer (score 2):

> as quiet as a mouse
>   as blind as a bat
>   as flat as a pancake
>   as clear as a bell
>
> as long as I've known him
>   as much as I respect him
>   as strange as it may seem
>   as difficult as that may be

The "as . . . as" correlative can take a noun phrase as easily as a complete content clause.   Indeed, "as easily as a complete content clause" counts as just such a use.   There is no clause in "a complete content clause".

A literal interpretation of "as much as" is *of the same amount as* or *to the same degree as*.   In your example, the TVA itself was potent propaganda *to the same degree* as the weaponry that it produced.

Another nearly-literal interpretation is some *range* of amounts or degrees, up to and including that of the example given.

Interpreting "as much as" to mean something like *despite that* is less literal still, approaching idiom.   It's a common enough interpretation, but it's also a common enough interpretation of contrast even when *nothing* marks it:

> I respect him very much.   I disagree with him this time.